# Default Phone Handler Google Playstore Policy. My app constantly rejected

Tags: java, android, permissions

Hoping someone can help me with an ongoing frustrating issue with trying to publish one of my Android Apps written in Java to the Google Playstore. Everytime I try to publish it to the Google Playstore, I receive a rejection letter (from what feels like an automated rejection letter from their compliancy department.)

Below is the letter from Google, my code in question, and my Android Manifest listing the permissions. I have tried at least 20 attempts to modify the code to be compliant and each time no matter what I changed, it has failed to get past their filters. Anyone know anything about how to implement code on making your phone a default phone handler or can anyone se what is wrong with my default handler situation?

"Letter from Playstore"

**Issue with your app

**After reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t comply with the Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policy. An app can use Call Log or SMS permissions only when it is acting as a designated default handler or its core functionality falls within a permitted use case.
Apps must be actively registered as the default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handler before prompting users to accept any SMS or Call Log permissions. Those apps must immediately stop using the permission when they’re no longer the default handler.
You declared default Phone handling in your declaration form, but your app isn’t the registered default handler for phone or its other core functionality.

I have tried to change the order in which the permission request present themselves. As of now I have the default handler prompt showing up first and if the user opts NO, the app doesnt work. I cannot understand what can be more compliant than that.

```
//my code

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telecom.TelecomManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView currentStateTV;
    private ImageButton ringtoneIB;

    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private int currentMode;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefs";
    private static final String KEY_SHARED_SETTING_EXECUTED = "sharedSettingExecuted";

    private boolean isSharedSettingExecuted = false;
    private TelecomManager telecomManager;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private boolean isPermissionGranted = false; // Added flag to track permission status

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    currentStateTV = findViewById(R.id.currentStateTV);
    ringtoneIB = findViewById(R.id.ringer);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    isSharedSettingExecuted = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_SHARED_SETTING_EXECUTED, false);

    telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
    boolean isDefaultDialer = getPackageName().equals(telecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage());

   ** if (!isDefaultDialer && !isSharedSettingExecuted) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Set as Default Phone App");
    builder.setMessage("Would you like to set this app as your default phone app?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER);
    intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
    startActivity(intent);
    performCodeBlock2();});

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "App is not set as the default phone handler",  

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();});
    builder.show();} else {
    performCodeBlock2();}**

    // Set up OnClickListener for ringtoneIB
    ringtoneIB.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ringtone Mode Activated..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    currentStateTV.setText("Ringtone Mode Activated..");});

    // Set up OnClickListener for button
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {


    Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
    });

    // Set up OnClickListener for hideButton
    ImageButton hideButton = findViewById(R.id.hideme);
    hideButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    currentStateTV.setText("Ringtone Mode Silent (APP RUNNING)");
    currentStateTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != 

    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "App disabled until permissions accepted. Close & Restart App", 

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} 
    else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Good to Go! Hiding App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    view.postDelayed(() -> moveTaskToBack(true), 2000);
    });
    }

    private void performCodeBlock2() {
    if (!isSharedSettingExecuted) {
    isSharedSettingExecuted = true;
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_SHARED_SETTING_EXECUTED,
    isSharedSettingExecuted).apply();
    } else {
    return; // Skip code block 2 if already executed
    }

    currentMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();

    switch (currentMode) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
    currentStateTV.setText("Ringer Mode");
    break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
    currentStateTV.setText("Ringer Mode Silent");
    break;
    default:
    currentStateTV.setText("Fail to get mode");
        }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)  
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    **if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&   
    !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,  
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, 
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] 
    {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[].   
    {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    } else {
    isPermissionGranted = true; // Permission is already granted
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] 
    grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (!isPermissionGranted) { // Check if permission was not already granted
    if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    isPermissionGranted = true;
    }
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if   (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, 
    Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 11);
                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 11);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            case 11: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }**
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
        boolean isDefaultDialer = getPackageName().equals(telecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage());

        if (!isDefaultDialer) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("isPermissionGranted", isPermissionGranted);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        isPermissionGranted = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isPermissionGranted", false);
    }
}
```

//my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication123"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".NewActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".CallReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```